# DeepLab Tensorflow: TypeError: MonitoredTrainingSession() got an unexpected keyword argument 'summary_dir'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm running [this DeepLab example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/pascal.md) on an Deep Learning AMI (ubuntu) ec2 instance inside the provided conda environment `tensorflow_p36`.

From `~/models/research` I'm running:

```
PATH_TO_INITIAL_CHECKPOINT=/home/ubuntu/models/research/deeplab/datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/train/model.ckpt-0.index

PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR=/home/ubuntu/models/research/deeplab/datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/eval

PATH_TO_DATASET=/home/ubuntu/models/research/deeplab/datasets/pascal_voc_seg/VOCdevkit/VOC2012

python deeplab/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --training_number_of_steps=30000 \
    --train_split="train" \
    --model_variant="xception_65" \
    --atrous_rates=6 \
    --atrous_rates=12 \
    --atrous_rates=18 \
    --output_stride=16 \
    --decoder_output_stride=4 \
    --train_crop_size=513 \
    --train_crop_size=513 \
    --train_batch_size=1 \
    --dataset="pascal_voc_seg" \
    --tf_initial_checkpoint=${PATH_TO_INITIAL_CHECKPOINT} \
    --train_logdir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_dir=${PATH_TO_DATASET}
```

and the output is

```
INFO:tensorflow:Training on train set
INFO:tensorflow:Ignoring initialization; other checkpoint exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deeplab/train.py", line 500, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "deeplab/train.py", line 492, in main
    hooks=[stop_hook]) as sess:
TypeError: MonitoredTrainingSession() got an unexpected keyword argument 'summary_dir'
```

If I comment out line 488 of `~/models/research/deeplab/train.py`, `summary_dir=FLAGS.train_logdir,` and run the code from above again then the result is

```
INFO:tensorflow:Training on train set
INFO:tensorflow:Ignoring initialization; other checkpoint exists
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2019-03-16 02:34:49.871433: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/ubuntu/models/research/deeplab/datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/eval/model.ckpt-0
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into /home/ubuntu/models/research/deeplab/datasets/pascal_voc_seg/exp/train_on_trainval_set/eval/model.ckpt.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I Upgrade my tensorflow version to 1.10.0. 
I also [upgrade cuda](https://medium.com/@zhanwenchen/install-cuda-and-cudnn-for-tensorflow-gpu-on-ubuntu-79306e4ac04e) version to 9.0 but don't know it's compulsory or not.

Then run with Python3.

It's solved my problem.

You can try this. Hope It will help.